# Convert string Lambda expression to method

Tags: c#, lambda

Edit: Basically I need functions (x/2,..) selected from `comboBox` drawn with `Draw()` function.
I need to write a code that draws a graph of function. I have a delegate:

```
delegate float Function(float x);
```

My drawing function:

```
void Draw(Function f)
{
    Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
    for (float i = -100; i < 100; i+=0.1f) 
    {
        g.DrawString(".", new Font("arial", 10), Brushes.Black, i+200, ClientSize.Height-(f(i) + 100));
    }
}
```

On MainFormLoad I load my arrays (this might not be the correct method of doing this, but I am a little bit lost how to do it). `arr` contains function that i want to draw.

```
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr;
    arr = new string[] {"x / 2", "50 * Math.Sin(x / 50.0)"};
    var arr = from item in arr select item;
    foreach (var i in arr)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
    }
}
```

And then on ButtonClick I try to call it:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Draw(x => x / 2) It should work this way
    Draw(x => (Combobox1. something here ?));
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to retrieve the value from the combo box in order to draw using the selected function?

Comment: Yes, but the value is in string and in needs to be converted to lambda expression so first item from arr is "x/2" so x => x/2. Am I complicating it too much ?

Comment: There are [libraries that do that for you](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).

Comment: What libraries, I don't want to use some external libraries, maybe linq but i don't know if thats helps and if yes i am lost with it.

Comment: Actually it is from Microsoft C# examples, you could take the .cs file and just add it in to your project and use it. Look at the article I linked to in the previous comment and read it.

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see it, I came across this site, but i still don't know how to apply that to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you commented you do not want external libraries, but I have just finished my answer when I read that. So, this is it. You can use [Ncalc](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/), it is very easy to use, check this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var strFunc = "10000/x";
        for (var i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var strFuncRplacement = strFunc.Replace("x", i.ToString());
            var e = new Expression(strFuncRplacement);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Evaluate());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You just have to install the nuget package and the using directive

```
using NCalc;
```

And this way you could save a lot of effort and code lines

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but I think you could do it like this:

instead of

```
void Draw(Function f)
```

use

```
void Draw(Func<double, double> f)
```

and instead of

```
arr = new string[] {"x / 2", "50 * Math.Sin(x / 50.0)"};
```

use

```
var arr = new Func<double, double>[] {(double x) => x/2, (double x) => Math.Sin(x)};
```

Comment: And with what parameter do I call `Draw()` function in `Button1click` ? How do I get it from comboBox ?

Comment: Uh, I kinda forgot about the combobox part and I can't really see a solution for that :/ sorry

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to declare the functions as string type and not Function type?

If no then simple change the array arr to array of Function and initiate it with Functions .

If yes, it is not possible because you can not convert a string into c# code using only standart librarys in c#.